# onLoad or similar for Ajax?

Tags: ajax

Good day,

I was wondering if there is a way to make Ajax move on to the next code segment only when all the elements included in the server-side code page are fully loaded. When the retrieved data is text-only there’s no problem, but sometimes there are photos included.

This is part of the code I have been using:

```
xajx.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(xajx.readyState==4){
    document.all.div1.innerHTML = xajx.responseText;
    document.all.div1.style.display = “”;
  }
}
```

The thing is that when the response is retrieved (readyState set to 4) and div1 is displayed, the Photo has not been completely loaded yet, so actually the user can see the process of the picture slowly appearing, as he would in any other “normal” case. What I want to do is making div1 available for display only once all the components are fully loaded while meanwhile the system does its stuff in the background. Before Ajax I used hidden iframes like everybody, so I could enclose an onload event handler within the iframe tag (or in an external script), so div1 would appear only after the iframe has fully loaded, photos included.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the 'onload' event on images themselves. You'll need to work out how to attach that event when you are downloading the code dynamically as in your case.